# Use find results as command line argument for another process

Tags: linux, vim, find

How can I use `find` results as a command line argument for another process?

For example:

```
find -type f -iname "server*error*log" | vim ??
```

How to make vim to open returned filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find -type f -iname "server*error*log" -exec vim {} \;
```

The placeholder `{}` will get replaced by the actual filename. The `-exec` command needs to get terminated with the `\;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want not just one file, but many, to be acted on by one program (in your case editing in Vim), I think you want to pass it to `xargs`:

```
find -type f -iname "server*error*log" | xargs vim
```